# Rails HTTP client library

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anyone suggest me a good http client library for rails? I have to do some http calls to other servers from my server.

My ruby version is 1.9.x and rails is 3.1.

A link to some good documentation is welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

Comment: what kind of calls are you making?  where is the stdlib failing? what have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We use [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) for a lot of our projects and it has come very useful and well documented.

[HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) is another good one

Comment: Faraday is great since it allows you to create your own custom middleware and use them with it. Very flexible :D

Answer (score 0):

Check out this awesome slideshow comparison:

http://www.slideshare.net/HiroshiNakamura/rubyhttp-clients-comparison

Depends on the strengths of the library:

For speed: em-http-request, curb w/ multi
HTML operation, cookies: Mechanize
Api client: Faraday and other adapter based implementations
SSL, Conectivity: http-client